# Salonized widget doens't load on navigation change

Tags: html, angular

I have the widget of Salonized in my website. Now when I change through navigation and go back to it, it doesn't load anymore, only when I reload the page manually again it does.
Anyone have experience with this, or a solution on how to fix it?
widget code in component html:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Afspraken</h2>

<div class="salonized-booking" data-company="xxx" data-color="#199ba4" data-language="nl" data-height="700" data-inline="true" data-outline="shadow" data-widget_id="xxx"></div>
```

I had to add a  so I added it in index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NagelstudioWebsite</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://static-widget.salonized.com/loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

For the navigation, I'm using this app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { PricesComponent } from './prices/prices.component';
import { AppointmentsComponent } from './appointments/appointments.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { InspirationComponent } from './inspiration/inspiration.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'about' , component: AboutComponent},
    {path: 'prices' , component: PricesComponent},
    {path: 'appointment' , component: AppointmentsComponent},
    {path: 'blog' , component: BlogComponent},
    {path: 'contact' , component: ContactComponent},
    {path: 'inspiration' , component: InspirationComponent},
];
```

And this is my app.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container autosize>
  <mat-sidenav [ngClass]="!isCollapsed ? 'expanded' : ''" [mode]="isMobile ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="isMobile ? 'false' : 'true'">
    <mat-nav-list>

      <a mat-list-item [routerLink] = "'/'"> 
        <span class="entry">
           <mat-icon>house</mat-icon>
           <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">Homepage</span>
        </span>
     </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink] = "'/about'">
        <span class="entry">
           <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
           <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">Over mij</span>
        </span>
     </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink] = "'/prices'">
        <span class="entry">
           <mat-icon>sell</mat-icon>
           <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">Prijslijst</span>
        </span>
     </a>
     <a mat-list-item [routerLink] = "'/appointment'">
      <span class="entry">
         <mat-icon>event note</mat-icon>
         <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">Maak je afspraak!</span>
      </span>
   </a>
   <a mat-list-item [routerLink] = "'/inspiration'">
      <span class="entry">
         <mat-icon>photo_camera</mat-icon>
         <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">inspiratie</span>
      </span>
   </a>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink] = "'/blog'">
        <span class="entry">
           <mat-icon>feed</mat-icon>
           <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">Blog</span>
        </span>
     </a>
     <a mat-list-item [routerLink] = "'/contact'">
      <span class="entry">
         <mat-icon>call</mat-icon>
         <span *ngIf="!isCollapsed">Contact</span>
      </span>
   </a>
      
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```